# Unable to configure lampp server, stuck in splash screen

Tags: server, lamp, xampp

I installed lampp server (downloaded the .tar.xz file then extracted to the /opt folder) on my ubuntu 12.10 machine, I'm able to start apache, mysql and everything else but when I open the browser and go to localhost it gives me the xampp splash screen, where I can choose the language but even if I choose a language it redirects me to the same page.

Is there anything I have to setup that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and in my case the problem was I didn't have enough space in disk to create new temp file. I found also another solution [here](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?p=162795) which is

> read/write permissions on the `/opt/lampp/htdocs/xampp/lang/lang.tmp`

.

HTH